# How to swipe with finger in a View flipper?

Tags: android, android-layout, swipe, viewflipper

I have a view flipper containing two layouts with button. Now the issue is i am not able to swipe along with finger. Basically the view should swipe along with the finger. I hope you are getting what i am trying to say. Here is the onTouchevent code :-

```
    bottomFormatFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.bottomFormatFlipper);

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) 
    {
        switch (touchevent.getAction())
        {

        // when user first touches the screen to swap
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        {
            lastX = touchevent.getX();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        {
            float currentX = touchevent.getX();

            // if left to right swipe on screen
            if (lastX < currentX) 
            {
                // If no more View/Child to flip
                if (bottomFormatFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                    break;

                // set the required Animation type to ViewFlipper
                // The Next screen will come in form Left and current Screen will go OUT from Right 
                bottomFormatFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);
                bottomFormatFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);
                // Show the next Screen
                bottomFormatFlipper.showNext();
            }

            // if right to left swipe on screen
            if (lastX > currentX)
            {
                if (bottomFormatFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                    break;
                // set the required Animation type to ViewFlipper
                // The Next screen will come in form Right and current Screen will go OUT from Left 
                bottomFormatFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_right);
                bottomFormatFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);
                // Show The Previous Screen
                bottomFormatFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
            break;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

From this code, when i swipe, then after a second or so, the swipe animation occurs. I want that the view should swipe with my finger

Comment: you should use viewpager rather viewflipper

Comment: @BirajZalavadia - Thanks. Viewpager is the solution